# Como abrir um formulário de outro site com campos pré-preenchidos com PHP / HTML / JAVASCRIPT?

Tags: php, javascript, html, formulário

Olá. 
Estou melhorando a atualização de boleto dos clientes no meu site e preciso de ajuda.
Atualmente há um botão de atualizar boleto na página de ADM que os usuários utilizam, onde o mesmo redireciona os usuários para a página de atualização de boleto do site do banco que eles optaram utilizar (um site externo).
Chegando nessa página, há um formulário com alguns campos pedindo informações do boleto vencido do usuário.
Tudo funciona perfeitamente, o único problema é o trabalho que os usuários passam preenchendo esse formulário. 
Quero implementar algum método que preencha automaticamente esses dados para os usuários, porém, não estou conseguindo encontrar nada que me ajude nisso.

Comment: Este outro site, você irá adaptá-lo para receber os dados, ou não pode modificá-lo? Somente através do seu site, não há como. É uma questão de segurança.

Comment: Não modificá-lo, mas passar os dados para ele e, dessa maneira, preencher os campos contidos no formulário dele. Entende?

Comment: Essa sua pergunta dá margem à gente interpretar que vc está querendo hackear algum site. Se suas intenções forem boas recomendo que reformule a pergunta. Caso vá fazer isso, coloque o que vc já tentou fazer. Este é um site de dúvidas técnicas não um site pra fazer as coisas pra vc.

Comment: @EduardoMartinsCasagrande isso é o mesmo que modificar.

Comment: Por favor dê uma olhada no [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e leia o tópico [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) antes de postar. Boas perguntas normalmente têm um  [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). O StackOverflow também tem uma [Central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) com muita informação. Grato.

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira peço desculpas, não foi o que quis dizer. Assim está melhor?

Comment: @EduardoMartinsCasagrande na questão de ver quais suas intenções melhorou. Mas esse não é o modelo de dúvidas técnicas do site. O melhor uso é algum código que esteja apresentando algum problema e vc coloca na pergunta pra que o pessoal veja qual o erro. Uma pergunta perguntando genericamente como fazer algo dificilmente terá alguma resposta. Vc precisa mostrar algum código com problema pra ser auxiliado.

Comment: Mas só pra procurar lhe auxiliar de alguma forma, se fosse um site simples, talvez vc conseguisse fazer um wrapper carregando todo o site externo em um elemento do seu site. Como é um site de banco eu acho difícil vc conseguir fazer algo como isso pq certamente a segurança do site vai barrar e ver como uma intrusão qualquer alteração. Imagina se vc conseguisse alterar via Javascript à sua vontade os dados de um site de banco. Certamente isso inviabilizaria a presença de bancos na internet. E como eles estão na internet, obviamente já inventaram soluções pra impedir isso. Mesmo para boletos.

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira mas por exemplo, sabe quando preenchemos apenas um campo de um formulário de endereço e todos os outros são preenchidos automaticamente? Não há nenhuma forma de fazer algo parecido com isso, mas sem que o usuário precise digitar nada? Não estou querendo alterar alguma coisa no site externo, estou precisando apenas preencher os campos de forma automática.

Comment: Isso é feito pelo código do próprio site. Não de um site externo.

Answer (score 0):

Depende muito do banco. Desconheço se isso está documentado em algum lugar, mas por exemplo, no Banco do Brasil você consegue passando os parâmetros por GET:

https://www63.bb.com.br/portalbb/boleto/boletos/hc21e.bbx?campo1=00190&campo2=00009&campo3=01425&campo4=096029&campo5=31376&campo6=427170&campo7=9&campo8=75100000097571

Já mostra a página com os valores preenchidos nesse caso. Você vai precisar fazer isso para todos os bancos que seu sistema suporta. Seu cliente não terá trabalho, mas em compensação você vai sofrer um pouco rs. Talvez precise entrar em contato com cada banco para saber como proceder, ou fazer como fiz esse teste, entrei na página de atualizar boleto, vi o fonte do formulário e na tentativa e erro funcionou.